# How do I search datasets through the using search using our Enterprise?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, toolbar, search

So when you have layer that is missing or has a exclamation point next to the layer.
Now, I am not sure where to find the dataset because our enterprise system in Citrix has thousands of dataset all over.
When I use that search toolbox to find the layer that is missing and it came up nothing or doesnt work.
It would say "Warning  Enterprise search services are not found.
Use Search Options dialog in the search toolbar to register them. I have never use that system in Citrix.
Can you please advise me?
We have C hard drive on our computer but the T drive is what we use to find or save our datasets on our network.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and using Citrix.

Comment: As far as I have experienced. network drives cannot be indexed for the esri search toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to first right click on the layer with the exclamation.
Open the layer properties and go to the source tab and read the names in the source.
They will usually give me a clue as to where the original data came from.

For instance if the original was in the data/OK/schools/2014 folder.
The new location might look like
c:/program files/ArcGIS/ok/schools/2014/myshpfile.shp.
If it is a table in an egdb it might be harder to locate (if you have more than one egdb)
Then go to the repair data flyout (if there is more than one broken link in your mxd).